# Ubuntu Builder not launch

Tags: 13.10

I tried a install Ubuntu-Builder from [this](https://launchpad.net/~f-muriana/+archive/ubuntu-builder) site, i installed it with USC, but when i launch it, a few seconds loading and nothing... I tried purge it and install with adding ppa repository and again install it, but didn’t helped... I use Ubuntu 13.10 64 bit with last updates... I tried restart, but not helped.

Comment: I have the same issue; did you manage to get it resolved? Thanks, CS

Answer (score 1):

Try launching it from the terminal, with the command `sudo ubuntu-builder` .